# How to find the SUM and average of an integer input by the user in Java?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, user-input

I need to check what the user input is and only run the program when the user inputs a positive integer. If they input a number less than 0, I need to ask them to re-input a positive number. I have been able to do this, however, I can't figure out how to actually allow them to input another number.

All that outputs is "Wrong value, please write a positive integer". But the only way to input another integer is to re-run the program. I want to to be able to input another integer next to that output line.

Output e.g.

```
Please input a positive integer number N: -100

Wrong value, please write a positive integer: 100

[PROGRAM]
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SumAndAverage {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("*********");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("Please input a positive integer number: ");

    int N = keyboard.nextInt();

    if(N < 0){

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Wrong value, please write a positive integer");

        } else{

            int i = 1 ;

            int sum = 0;

            while(i <= N)
            {
                sum += i;
                i++;
            }

            double dec = sum;

            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("The sum from 1 to " + N + " is: " + sum);
            System.out.println();
            System.out.printf("The average is: %.1f%n", dec/N);
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("*********");

            keyboard.close();
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Use a while loop. I could be more useful, but you didn't provide your code.

Comment: Sorry, provided now

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In order to re-prompt the user to input another value, you will need to use a *while loop*

Here is what your code could look something like...

```
boolean validInput = false;
int inputNum;

while(!validInput){
    System.out.println("Please input a positive integer number N:");
    inputNum = keyboard.nextInt();
    if(num > 0)
    {
        validInput = true;  // if number is positive, loop will be exited
    }                       // otherwise, it will prompt the user again
}

// Whatever you want to do with the input (inputNum) //
```

Keep in mind that you should be handle cases if the user inputs something that isn't a number, etc, so your program doesn't break.